# Incompatible assignment to enum from enum *

Tags: c, pointers, enums

My code got an error below: 
`incompatible types when assigning to type enum cell from type enum cell *`

I have tried many ways to fix it but didnt work. This is my code:

```
BOOLEAN init_first_player(struct player * first, enum cell * token) {
    strcpy(first->name, "Bob");
    first->score = 0;

    int colorNo = rand() % 2;
    token = (colorNo + 1 == 1) ? RED : BLUE;

    first->token = token; //Error occurs here
    return TRUE;
}

this is my data structure:

struct Player {
    char name[20];
    enum cell token; //takes 0 - 1 - 2
    unsigned score;
};

enum cell {
    BLANK, RED, BLUE
};
```

Someone can please fix the code as I don't know what I have been doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you passing `enum cell * token` to the function when all you do with it is use it like a local variable?

Comment: How is `init_first_player()`called, what are you passing and how are those values defined and initialised?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a pointer and a thing that is not a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `init_first_player` `token` is a pointer to enum

In your structure `first`, `token` is an enum.

You cannot assign a pointer to enum to an enum.

You should use

```
*token = (colorNo + 1 == 1) ? RED : BLUE;
first->token = *token
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `token` in as a pointer, *presumably because you want to see the modified value at the call site*.  (If you don't care about the modified value, you shouldn't send it in this function at all).

So, you need to dereference it when assigning:

```
// use *token (instead of just token) to dereference and assign
*token = (colorNo + 1 == 1) ? RED : BLUE;
```

Same when assigning it to `first->token`:

```
first->token = *token;
```

Comment: Thank you very much